# CSS Absolute position submenu shows scroll bar on parent container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm working on a WordPress site, its menu has strange issue on one page, the menus on other pages are fine.

**Its normal structure is like this**

```
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="menu-title">Main Level 1</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-item" style="width:267.5px;">
    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
</li>
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"><span class="menu-title">Main Level 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When I mouseover on a menu item which has sub menus, some scrollbars appear. The CSS logic is

**submenu have absolute position**,

**the parent menu has overflow: hidden**

**When mouseover parent menu overflow: visible**

**css logic summary**

```
 <style>
    ul.nav-menu li.menu-item{
    position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    ul.nav-menu li.menu-item:hover{
     overflow: visible;
    }
 ul.sub-menu-item{
      position: absolute;
     }
    </style>
```

[image]

The strange thing is, this issue only happen on this kind of pages.

URL [Page with issue](http://www.vavajo.com/product/%E6%84%9B%E5%9C%A8%E5%A4%95%E9%99%BD%E3%81%AE%E9%80%81%E7%A6%AE%E7%B5%84%E5%90%88/)

URL [Doesn't have issue](http://www.vavajo.com/)

Does someone know the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `overflow-x: hidden` from `<div id="cms-page"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your div structure enclosing problem missing of other pages.

<div id="cms-page" class="cms-page"> **This div close after footer tag.**

Please follow: 
**<div id="cms-page" class="cms-page">**
 <header></header>
 <main></main>
 <footer></footer>
**</div>**
```